# Using xlib in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, xlib

Is it possible to use xlib (or any other libraries) in linux kernel module?

If yes how the makefile will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use any libraries from userspace (such as xlib) in kernel modules.